# Error made in checking the 'has a UK visa been refused before'

Tags: visas, uk, applications, ghanaian-citizens

I am a Ghanaian citizen. I made a mistake in filling out the application for a UK standard visitor's visa. When asked 'if I have been refused a UK visa before,' I checked no but I was refused a UK visa last year. I have submitted the form online and will be making a submission tomorrow. What should I do?